# VBA match function mismatch despite having the search value in source

Tags: excel, vba

```
Option Explicit

Sub ExtractDivFromAastocks()

    Dim StockCode As String, Anchor As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    StockCode = "02800"
    Anchor = "Announce Date"
    Set ws = ExtractRawDivFromAastocks(StockCode)
    Call CleanAastocksDiv(StockCode, ws)

End Sub

Private Function ExtractRawDivFromAastocks(StockCode As String)

    Dim WsFound As Boolean
    Dim i As Integer
    WsFound = False

    For i = 1 To Sheets.Count():
        If Worksheets(i).Name = StockCode Then
            WsFound = True
        End If
        If WsFound = True Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    If WsFound = True Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Worksheets(StockCode).Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim qt As QueryTable

    Dim Website As String, Aastock As String

    Aastock = "http://www.aastocks.com/en/stocks/analysis/dividend.aspx?symbol="

    Website = Aastock & StockCode

    Set ws = Sheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count()))
    ws.Name = StockCode

    Set qt = ws.QueryTables.Add( _
                Connection:="URL;" & Website, _
                Destination:=ws.Range("A1"))

    With qt
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = True
        .Refresh

    End With

    Set ExtractRawDivFromAastocks = ws

End Function

Private Sub CleanAastocksDiv(StockCode As String, ws As Worksheet)

    Dim StartRow As Integer

    StartRow = Application.Match("Announce Date", ws.Range("A:A"), 0)

    ws.Range("A1:" & _
                ws.Cells(StartRow - 1, ws.Columns.Count()).Address).EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

The worksheet indeed has the string value in it, and I have no idea why the match fails. I have tried using the Match function on the sheet itself, it works. Could this be some kind of reference issues? The cell in the sheet doesn't seem to have weird whitespaces. It would be really great if anyone can help me with this:

[image]

Comment: That looks ok, the error is because the search fails. Are you sure `ws` is the same sheet as the screenshot? Make sure there are no extra spaces on the end on the string in A80

Comment: Added the entire code. Shouldn't be whitespace issue because I tried using the match function on the sheet itself.

Comment: This is a bit wrong - `Set ws = ExtractRawDivFromAastocks(StockCode)` The code is asking from a function to do too many things. E.g., add a worksheet, return it, take data from a query table, and refresh it. At the end it returns a worksheet. It is a good idea to refactor it.

Comment: Just wondering - can you call the function like this `CleanAastocksDiv StockCode, ws` instead of `Call CleanAastocksDiv(StockCode, ws)`?

Comment: The query was not complete when the code searches for the cell!

Comment: After I set qt.backgroundquery = False, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Worksheets(1)
    Dim StartRow As Variant

    StartRow = Application.Match("Announce Date", ws.Range("A:A"), 0)

    If IsError(StartRow) Then Exit Sub
    If StartRow < 2 Then Exit Sub

    ws.Range("A1:A" & StartRow - 1).EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

---

- Declare `StartRow` as a `Variant`, because if `Announce Date` does not exist, it would return an error;
- It can be checked with the `IsError(StartRow)` and exit if it is not the case;
- `If StartRow < 2 Exit Sub` is needed to avoid a possible error if StartRow is 1;